# Overwrite image cropping defaults only for page resources

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

I would like to overwrite the image cropping configuration specifically for the page resources.

In the [changelog](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/core/8.7/Changelog/8.6/Feature-75880-ImplementMultipleCroppingVariantsInImageManipulationTool.html) i can find the following part:

> It is also possible to set the cropping configuration only for a specific tt_content element type by using the columnOverrides feature:
>
> $GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['types']['textmedia']['columnsOverrides']['assets']['config']['overrideChildTca']['columns']['crop']['config'] = [
> 'cropVariants' => [

I ask myself if there is the possibility to do this specifically for the media files in the page resources.

I tried something like this:

```
$GLOBALS['TCA']['pages']['types']['media']['columnsOverrides']['assets']['config']['overrideChildTca']['columns']['crop']['config'] = [
```

But this does not work.

Maybe this does just not work. But if it does i'm looking forward for some hints to achieve this.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$GLOBALS['TCA']['pages']['columns']['media']['config']['overrideChildTca']['columns']['crop']['config']['cropVariants']`
will do the job to change the cropVariants for **all pagetypes**.

If you want to change the cropVariants for a **special pagetype**, you have to use
`$GLOBALS['TCA']['pages']['types']['THE_PAGE_TYPE']['columnsOverrides']['media']['config']['overrideChildTca']['columns']['crop']['config']['cropVariants']`

Comment: Your example for all pagetypes does work.

In the case that any other ran into the issues, i myself can not confirm that the config example for special pagetypes does work, but it looks very promising.

Thanks Kevin for your help!

Comment: Here an working example extension https://github.com/frans-beech-it/t3ext-config_examples/blob/master/Configuration/TCA/Overrides/pages_cropvariants.php

Answer (score 0):

You are basically correct but you need to refer to a [`type` value](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/Ctrl/Index.html#type) to get this working. For the `pages` table this would be [any value for `doktype`](https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/blob/9aed02351af27f103548b8ab01157330bca62567/typo3/sysext/core/Configuration/TCA/pages.php#L67-L129).

Thus something the following would work:

```php
$GLOBALS['TCA']['pages']['types'][(string)\TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\Page\PageRepository::DOKTYPE_DEFAULT]['columnsOverrides']['assets']['config']['overrideChildTca']['columns']['crop']['config'] = [ ... ];
```

This sets the cropping configuration only for pages of type *Standard*.

If you only want to set this for a few selected pages, you'll need to add your own `doktype`.

Comment: Maybe i have not fully understand the part with the doktype. But [Kevins Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45052173/7104555) does the job. 

But no matter, thanks for the answer! Maybe this will help some others.

Comment: He wrote basically the same, only that used a concrete value instead of `'THE_PAGE_TYPE'`. ;-) But yes, if you want to affect all page types, use the mentioned first example.